# Android R.java keep not updating

Tags: android, updating

I'm a new learner in android programming. I have reading book about android programming and currently practicing. I have one little problem but it's annoying.

My R.java file does not updating with any change I made. Like when I drag an image, or create XML file. The R.java does not updating. I have search about the problem and found a solution to clean the project and then make changes to manifest.xml to force generated of R.java file. 
When I doing that the R.java update with any change I made previously. But when I made new changes the R.java does not update again. Must I do that clean and force generated R.java file every time I want to run my project?or is there is some way to fix it?

The Build Automatically is checked by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run a clean on the project, R.java should be updated or regenerated. If it doesn't, there probably is some issue in the res/ folder.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11869307/r-java-file-not-getting-generated) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757107/developing-for-android-in-eclipse-r-java-not-generating) post might be useful to you.

Comment: I think I found the my problem.. My project is not build everytime I make something new because I use capital letter on the file name and preventing the project to build.. thanks for the answer anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Do these things,anyone of this will help you

1. Project -> Clean,
   Right click -> Fix Project Properties
2. Restart Eclipse
3. make some fake modification in manifest and save
4. check your console for any error message
5. check your drawable folder, check the image names satisfy the rules