# R.java not getting generated

Tags: android, r.java-file

When the android project is build automatically i get the following error:

```
[2014-12-09 01:51:22 - FlashLight] /root/Desktop/Andriod/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/21.1.1/aapt: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /root/Desktop/Andriod/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/21.1.1/aapt)

[2014-12-09 01:51:22 - FlashLight] /root/Desktop/Andriod/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/21.1.1/aapt: /lib/libz.so.1: no version information available (required by /root/Desktop/Andriod/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/21.1.1/aapt)
```

I tried the solutions provided in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11869307/r-java-file-not-getting-generated)  but none of them worked

I am using Eclipse Luna in fedora 10 with ADT plugin.

Comment: R.java is system generated...

Answer (score 0):

This error states that your environment is missing suitable libraries such as libstdc++ and libz. Did you try to reinstall them by running `apt-get install libstdc++6 libz` ?
Also why are you running this from roots workarea? aren`t you running some different user?

Comment: i checked that libstdc++ and libz libraries are up to date. I am using root account.

Comment: Did you check that they are placed correctly? You may also have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216399/usr-lib-libstdc-so-6-version-glibcxx-3-4-15-not-found 
There was the problem that gcc were handcompiled and not installed corretly